# How to change the default time given to a test execution for spec flow in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, specflow

So, I am executing a Web automation test on VS 2015 using C# and spec flow, Now this test normally takes more than 1 minute to execute.

So, I am facing two problems right now due to a single issue

1. I am searching for an element in a test scenario, if that element is not found in the one minute time frame, the test fails and exits(The one minute time frame, which I think is set by default in spec flow)
2. If that element is somehow found within the one minute time frame and test goes on to be successfully executed, I still get an error that the complete test has been skipped(Because it was not completed in 1 minute time frame)

Here is my default.srprofile file:::::::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
  <Settings projectName="PlentyOfFish(SpecFlow)" projectId="{e08ce6d1-5624-4562-bedf-42e1806c0c72}" />
  <Execution stopAfterFailures="1" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
  <!-- For collecting by a SpecRun server update and enable the following element. For using the 
      collected statistics, set testSchedulingMode="Adaptive" attribute on the <Execution> element.
    <Server serverUrl="http://specrunserver:6365" publishResults="true" />
  -->
  <TestAssemblyPaths>
    <TestAssemblyPath>PlentyOfFish(SpecFlow).dll</TestAssemblyPath>
  </TestAssemblyPaths>
  <DeploymentTransformation>
    <Steps>
      <!-- sample config transform to change the connection string-->
      <!--<ConfigFileTransformation configFile="App.config">
        <Transformation>
          <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
                <connectionStrings>
                  <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseForTesting;Integrated Security=True" 
                       xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" />
                </connectionStrings>
                            </configuration>
                        ]]>
        </Transformation>
      </ConfigFileTransformation>-->
    </Steps>
  </DeploymentTransformation>
</TestProfile>
```

Here is the screeshot for error
https://www.screencast.com/t/vZXJhkjMt

Highlights my first issue

Comment: Which test runner are you using? MsTest, NUnit, Xunit?

Comment: NUnit with Specflow+runner(Specrun.specflow)

Comment: So NUnit for Assertations and the SpecFlow+Runner for executing the tests? Could you post here more information of your project? Defaul.srProfile, Screenshot of the error, ... 
Or open an issue for the Runner here: http://specflow.org/specflow-support/
FYI: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+ and SpecFlow

Comment: Check out my recent edit, I have tried to be as detailed as possible

Comment: From the little error message that is visible, it looks like you get an timeout in Selenium which throws an exception.

Comment: I am positive that it is not a selenium problem. If it was selenium problem, Implicit or Explicit wait would have set it right. It is a problem with SpecFlow or NUnit as far as I think

Comment: Could you make a project for reproducing this issue and open with it an issue? I will  have a look at it.

Comment: I can not share with you the exact same project but I will try reproducing on a sample project